# How do you treat gradient as a vector?

Tags: vector-calculus, operators

I need to express $\nabla = (\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z)$ as a vector, so that I can compute the differential operator given by $A\cdot\nabla$ (where here $A$ is a 3x3 matrix) using Mathematica. Subsequently, I need to be able to do operations with $\nabla_A := A \cdot \nabla$ on a vector/scalar and get the differential operator applied to the vector/scalar (e.g. either $\nabla_A\cdot \vec{v}$ or $\nabla_A \vec{v}$ or $\nabla_A \sigma$, where $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$).

This comes down to treating $\nabla$ as a vector, which isn't allowed (as far as I can tell) by the Grad[-] function in Mathematica.

After browsing the documentation and forums, I couldn't figure out an easy way to try to do this. I am new to Mathematica, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it may be considered a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) and therefore  [off-topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please [edit] your question if you consider this is a mistake and give great emphasis in what was NOT answered in the other question. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If the other question does contain the answer you were looking for, do let us know in the comments.

Comment: It does, thanks! Sorry it was a dupilcate